# jQuery ajax stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My jQuery script stopped working when I moved my clients site from the dev-site to their own site (which basicly has the same setup using a VPS).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input[name=button]:button').click(function(){
    jQuery("#show").html('<center><img src="http://xxxx/images/ajax-loader.gif"></center>');
    jQuery.get("http://xxx/inc/usrreg_ajax.php",{
    namn: jQuery("input[name='namn']").val(),
    nyhetsbrev: jQuery("input[name='news']").val()}, 

    function(data){
        jQuery("#show").fadeIn("slow").html(data);

    });
});
});
```

im using the html

```
<div id="registering" style="margin-top: 15px;">
<div style="float:left;">
<label for="namn">Namn:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="namn"><br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="news" value="ja">Ja, jag vill ha nyhetsbrev! <br/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Anmäl dig!">
<div id="show"></div>
</div>
```

I've not made any changes post move and the jQuery script works perfect on the dev-site.

Very gratefull for any input!

All the best,
Marten

Comment: Are there any errors being printed out to the javascript console?  Have you used firebug to inspect what's going on?

Comment: Is jQuery being included anyplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it here http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/D4NuF/ and it works(get the image to show up), there must be a problem with the link to jQuery library.

Comment: that was my first thought aswell, but we're having other jquery scripts running (sliders etc). I've changed the jQuery library to another one but the problem still exists

Comment: I solved it, it was some problem with the jQuery library, but the strange part was that i tried both 1.5.1 and 1.6 from the local server. Worked with googles source

Answer (score 3):

Is `xxx/inc/usrreg_ajax.php` on the same domain as your new site?

You have to remember that there a same origin policy that, for security reasons, prevent you from perform ajax calls from other domain urls.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

> Due to browser security restrictions,
>   most "Ajax" requests are subject to
>   the same origin policy; the request
>   can not successfully retrieve data
>   from a different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol.

You can use `jsonp` for different domain calls, but you will have to use `jQuery.ajax` for that, and won't be able to get the html as simple as you are doing right now

Comment: xxx is on the same domain, thanks for your input though! I really appreciate it.